# My Ubuntu 20.04 is not booting properly

Tags: boot, 20.04, katoolin

After the Ubuntu's logo it is not taking me to the login window. Instead it is taking me to this-

Actually, all things were working properly unless I installed katoolin to my laptop.
I've also tried many suitable methods but they didn't work.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].